# How to detect CAPTCHA and solve it manually using selenium and python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, recaptcha, 2captcha

I'm working on simple program based on python and selenium.
The program fills all fields with some personal information and sends the information with "confirm" button.
Once the button is pressed, a CAPTCHA must be solved, is there a way to detect the captcha, solve it manually and then send the answer?
The program is in headless mode and I read that it is impossible to disable this mode when code is running...I was thinking to find the CAPTCHA as a "link" and open it on a second page maybe.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: maybe of help: [how-can-i-programatically-upload-captcha-images-to-this-solving-service-in-pytho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952677/how-can-i-programatically-upload-captcha-images-to-this-solving-service-in-pytho) - principially I would say your question as is has not enough meat in it to be on topic here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect captchas when scraping google?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39422359/how-to-detect-captchas-when-scraping-google)

Comment: Settings are basically for the life of the driver so unless it's in non headless it's not gonna be accessible for that.

Comment: Sure. You could just create a GUI in python which display the image and a textbox where you can enter the solved image. Then press a button which takes your input and hands it back to your code which can then enter it into the web element..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.